# Cannot connect to Azure Container Instance iperf endpoint via multiple ports

Tags: azure, docker, networking, azure-container-instances

I am currently evaluating a scenario from a customer where one container actually hosts multiple processes (bad practice) that each listens to one port. I want to host the container in Azure Container Instances or Azure Container Apps and I am currently struggeling with Azure Container Apps.

My test scenario is the following. I am using a simple alpine nginx (because is started with it). Inside that container I start two instances of iperf3. Why iperf? Needed a very simple way to expose certain ports.

```
FROM nginx

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install iperf3

COPY www /usr/share/nginx/html/www
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY my_wrapper_script.sh my_wrapper_script.sh

CMD ./my_wrapper_script.sh
```

my_wrapper_script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
  
# turn on bash's job control
set -m
  
# Start the primary process and put it in the background
iperf3 -s -p 8080 &
  
# Start the helper process
iperf3 -s -p 10113
```

I tested the container locally with this start command:
`docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 10113:10113 nginxtest`
and I was able to connect to it via iperf3.

This does not work in the ACI. I chose the following configuration:

- public network access (ACI gets DNS entry and public IP)
- enabled ports: 80, 8080 and 10113
- correct image is chosen.

I logged into the running container and validated that iperf3 is running:

```
root@SandboxHost-638182186910382121:/# netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN
tcp6       1      0 :::10113                :::*                    LISTEN      25/iperf3           
tcp6       1      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      24/iperf3
```

But I simply cannot connect to it:

```
./iperf3 -c 20.23.6.60 -p 8080
iperf3: error - control socket has closed unexpectedly
```

Does not work with -p 10113 of course. There is nothing in front of the ACI, no firewall and so on. What am I missing? Locally, I had to forward the ports during `docker run`. I am not able to specify this mapping in ACI.

What am I missing here?